# Google Apps Script link to a new page removes company tag from url

Tags: url, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have created a multi page app to use internally within our company.
However for some of my colleagues when using the app, whenever they click on a link to be directed to a new page, Chrome removes our company tag from the URL.

Normally the URL should be `https://script.google.com/a/macros/**companyname.eu**/s` and then the Script ID. But for some reason Chrome removes the `**companyname.eu**` part from the URL.

In the GScript I use the following code to make sure correct page is displayed -

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameters.v == 'wishes' || e.parameters.v == "agents" || e.parameters.v == 'markets' || e.parameters.v == 'team_leads'){
    let tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameters.v);
    return tmp.evaluate();
  } else {
    let tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("wishes")
    return tmp.evaluate();
  }
}
```

And then in the HTML files for the links themselves I am using the following code -

```
<header>
  <a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(); ?>?v=wishes">Pending Wishes</a>
  <a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(); ?>?v=agents">Agents</a>
  <a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(); ?>?v=markets">Markets</a>
  <a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(); ?>?v=team_leads">Team Leads</a>
</header>
```

For the same people using Safari instead of Google Chrome seems to fix the Issue.

Edit: Picture of the Publish Settings
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What is the question? Also, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

### The WebApp URL depends on how you publish the WebApp

- If you set `Who has access to the app:` to `only myself` or `Anyone within {Your domain}`, the WebApp URL will be of type

  https://script.google.com/a/YOURDOMAIN/macros/s/XXXXX/exec
- - If you set `Who has access to the app:` to `Anyone` or `Anyone, even anonymous`, the WebApp URL will be of type

  https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXX/exec

For your domain, please publish set the access to `Anyone within {Your domain}` and make sure that your domain users only open it when signed into their browser session with their domain account

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. However these are the publishing settings I have used and as I mentioned, this happens only to few of my colleagues where majority of them can use the tool just fine.

Comment: Likely this is related to the fact of either they are signed in with their domain account/ a different account / not at all. Can you see any pattern there? Did you try in Incongito mode? How is the WebApp currently published?

Comment: They are only logged in with their company account and thats all.

I've posted a picture of how the web app is published in this thread as well.

Comment: If it works fine inincognito it usually implies that the user is signed it with multiple accounts into his browser. Ask the affected users to sign out of all browser accounts and sign in with the company one. Please confirm that if you execute the WebApp as "me" instead of "User accessing the web app" and simultaneous "access within XXX" - the user that can access the app can see the URL correctly. How / where is the redirection link implemented?